# Why do I get warning C4034: sizeof returns 0?

Tags: c

I have a simple c project with 5 files.

Data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_INCLUDED
#define DATA_INCLUDED
struct NUMBERS {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};
#endif
```

Data.c

```
#include "Data.h"

struct NUMBERS Hello[] = {
    {11, 12, 13, 14},
    {15, 16, 17, 18},
    {19, 20, 21, 22},
    {23, 24, 25, 26}
};
```

Info.h

```
#ifndef INFO_INCLUDED
#define INFO_INCLUDED

extern struct NUMBERS Hello[];
extern int SizeOfHello;

#endif
```

Info.c

```
#include "Data.h"
#include "Info.h"

int SizeOfHello = sizeof Hello/sizeof(struct NUMBERS);
```

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Info.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%d\r\n", SizeOfHello);
    return 0;
}
```

I get

> warning C4034: sizeof returns 0

when I run the program and `printf()` outputs 0. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: It does not know the size of the `Hello` in `info.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must move the size computation to the file that actually **defines** the array, `Data.c`:

```
#include "Data.h"

struct NUMBERS Hello[] = {
    {11, 12, 13, 14},
    {15, 16, 17, 18},
    {19, 20, 21, 22},
    {23, 24, 25, 26}
};
int SizeOfHello = sizeof Hello/sizeof(struct NUMBERS);
```

It would be written more reliably this way:

```
int SizeOfHello = sizeof(Hello) / sizeof(*Hello);
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that, given a declaration

```
extern struct NUMBERS Hello[];
```

the compiler has no visibility of either `struct NUMBERS` nor the number of elements in `Hello`.

You need to initialise (and, preferably define) `SizeOfHello` in Data.c - where both those values are visible.  It would also be preferable to `include` info.h within Data.c, so the compiler has a fighting chance of detecting any mismatch between declarations and definitions.

Comment: The compiler should complain with an error, not just a warning.

Comment: Maybe so, chqrlie, but that's not pertinent to the question asked.